# Receive Push Notifications directly to the iOS (not linked with an application)

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, raspberry-pi, ibeacon

Any way we can achieve this, just need a basic approach, no need for codes or anything like that but some kind of conceptual guidance.

Step#1 User walks into a specific location where the Shop  ABC is located

Step #2 At that particular moment, some kind of device (iBeacon, Raspberry PI or something like that) recognize that this particular iPhone device is in close proximity and it sends a HTTP request to a third party server with some information.

Step #3 Third party server sends a notification to the device that it should download the ABC shop's app

OR
Raspberry PI or iBeacon identifies the device proximity and sends the same notification directly to the iPhone device without contacting the third party server.

Comment: You'd have to solve the problem of detecting that a phone walked in.  iBeacon claims to do that, but there, too, the user needs to have installed an app.

Comment: @danh yes, I looked into that but didn't work because it requires an application to run on the device. Looking at the Raspberry PI now for any hopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you must have an app configured to receive push notifications. Otherwise people would be getting unwanted push notifications from everyone. Also, in order to send a push notification you need to get the Device ID which you can only get with an app that you write that then transmits it to your server.

Comment: Thanks, I am up voting your answer as it is clear that push notifications cannot be used without an app, also I edited my question to something more generic.

Comment: Now I have another thing, I've noted if I install an application which receives push notifications and if I even delete that particular app, I still get some push notifications from their server as alert. Do you have any idea how it is been done ?

Comment: If that is truly happening, then that must be a bug in iOS. Once you delete an app you should no longer receive push notifications for it. Have you looked into how push notifications actually work? Your web service that "sends" the push notifications does not communicate with the device at all. You send a notification along with a device id to Apple's servers that then potentially delivers that to the device if the device 1. has the app installed and 2. has notifications enabled for that app.

Comment: Yes I went through the APN guidelines and actually we implemented an app which is working fine with APN. But we noted this issue sporadically and cannot get an exact cause for it. Also, I've noted the same issue several times in my Starbucks app that I receive notifications even when the app is deleted from the device.

Comment: For the question I asked, it seems there is no answer available in current context but your answer directly supported me to explain it to the client, thanks ! Please post if you find out a workaround.